# conversion to blender

Tags: conversion, blend4web, webgl

To give background:

Back in 2007 I started working on a model of the Great Crystal area of Final Fantasy XII using a modeling program named MilkShape3D. I wanted to be able to allow people to view the model on the web using a browser, but the OCX provided by the author has issues and never worked exactly the way I wanted it to (although it did render the models). To do it, the models had to be saved out in a format he called msz (the extension of the files generated was .msz). The model files natively were .ms3d files. The unfortunate part of all this is that the OCX required DirectX 9 to work. As we all know, Direct X is no longer supported by any browser, so the OCX is now useless.

To get to the point:

I am looking at Blender as a possible solution to making my models more current (as MilkShape3D is seemingly no longer supported), but conversion seems to be an issue. While MilkShape3D exports to a multitude of model formats, Blender doesn't seem to be one of them. Is there a known way I can convert my MilkShape3D models to Blender format?

To ask a second somewhat related question:

The new model-viewer control for web pages (<model-viewer>) uses the glTF format. Does Blender support this format, or does it have a different way to render models through a browser (if any)? (I think the blend4web tag answered this question in part.)

Comment: [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export.html) is the section in the Blender manual on import/export formats.

Comment: glFT is supported by an add-on. It's activated by default (File > Import) https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html

Comment: Thanks to both of you, John Eason and Blunder. Those links are just what I was looking for.